# How to remote manage a Hyper-V on Windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, remote

I have two computers:

- freshly installed latest stable Windows 10 pro
- have an exact same admin local account & password (user A)
- have an exact same admin account with online email login (user B)
- connected to the same router, mark network as "private"
- both open firewalls (with a "allow all" rule, not disabled)
- can remote desktop to each other

On one of them Hyper-V is installed, and a Linux guest: this is the "server".

Now I want to use another computer (as the "client") to connect the server.

I have tried modify DCOM permission, run many commands (about winrm) in PS, modify auth with "azman" ..... none of that works.

Is there anyone who ever succeeded to connect to a Windows 10 Pro Hyper-V server, or even connect to a Windows 10 Pro management console?
How do I do that?

Comment: Just because they have the same username and password doesn't mean they have the same user GUID, in order for PC A to authenticate with PC B you have to enable file sharing.  To make it clear it's not possible to access PC A with an account that exists on PC B but you can share files with them

Comment: You will need to authenticate to the server using the accounts for the server users who have appropriate permissions. Do that by authenticating using servername\username.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can login using "SERVER-COMPUTER-NAME\MyUser" instead of "MyUser"...

Answer (score -1):

This is about as correct as you can get. The only reason I could see this not working is if they are using the Windows account login. Then they will have to. I also made sure to go into *Control Panel* -> *System and Security* -> *System* -> *Remote settings* and re-tick *Only allow connections from computers running Remote Desktop with Network level Authentication (recommended)*. Then hit select user. Make sure the account has access.